# Python return status 200, but no response data

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, certificate, response, urllib3

I'm trying to acccess URL https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2711030 via urllib3. When doing I'am getting

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2711030'
headers = urllib3.make_headers(basic_auth='abc:xyz')
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
```

When I run above I get outpout as :

```
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
r.status
Out[38]: 200
r.read()
Out[39]: b''
r.data
Out[40]: b'<html><head><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /></head><body style="background-color:#FFFFFF" onload="var url=window.location.hash;if(url&&0!==url.length){document.cookie=\'oucrsnpdmeytwvuuiyfukjxfe_anchor=&quot;\'+encodeURIComponent(url) + \'&quot;\';}document.forms[0].submit()"><p><script language="javascript">document.write("Please wait ...");</script></p><noscript><p>Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.</p></noscript><form method="post" action="https://authn.hana.ondemand.com/saml2/sp/mds"><input type="hidden" name="tenantId" value="NzkwZmJmMjgtMjMxMC00M2E5LWI1NzEtN2MwYzliODg2ZTll"/><input type="hidden" name="idpName" value="aHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5zYXAuY29t"/><input type="hidden" name="requestUrl" value="aHR0cHM6Ly9sYXVuY2hwYWQuc3VwcG9ydC5zYXAuY29tLw=="/><input type="hidden" name="requestId" value="UzZlMmU1YjU3LTY0NmEtNDI0My1iMzk0LWMzYzNlZGRjOGU2Ni1pZXdCS2R6ZE5sR252RHVuVVlCTGlZd3lWZUNwazNsMmhJcXl6Z2VRNzgw"/><input type="hidden" name="relayState" value="b3VjcnNucGRtZXl0d3Z1dWl5ZnVranhmZQ=="/><input type="hidden" name="action" value="sso"/><input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SAZ4BbOwt1i/tJpwFLn6vV1cVUYT3AVv8BGaq+yAHXbCOd5E7swH9BnR8kxZu4mc5eLiclbZe94bN0X/b2EkS06QQIWQqsjL6UoDjTH0DA3y+qzrkIPyhYzM4mwZZlFx1NGJpmuWAn+2r063QI7Yuj7ebS2XhflW6k7qDKIZpPb8ctBsa6cJSUQFoqwHV6Km7spZYlGHwQ4ktER62ZSMvpmoFRAduOQfiJ1ckLl+iVxIsrTawZZz4+87MwmqjW2ym0qrxBLbZDHMdTvG+wggTweBpI2i043jAgy7blBLk5Yh92K8QLn3zsZ3NY+gTpgz1a+CYTr2vl35H8k5Kek4cg=="/><noscript><input type="submit" value="Continue"/></noscript></form></body></html>'
```

I want to read the page so that I can **scrape** data from it, what type of authentication do I need as I provided my login credential via which I access the page but then also no result.

What else do I need to provide or is there anything that I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: urllib3 doesnt use javascript, however the majority of this page is loaded via Javascript. Have you tried viewing this webpage in your browser with java script turned off. you will see that it actually doesnt show any content. Thats exactly how your python script will see it as most of the content is loaded via javascript which urllib3 doesnt do

Comment: yes, while disabling java script it gave same result as r.read(), how I can read page so that it read it as it is ?

Comment: You will need to use something like selenium and a browser driver to let browser events and javascript events reload and change html content.